# Install drivers for nvidia rtx 3060 Ubuntu 22.03 vmware esxi 8

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vmware

hi i tried to install nvidia driver version in ubuntu 22.04 using vmware esxi 8

with this command ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-525.89.02.run -m=kernel-open then i reboot vm

im getting this error:

when i run this: nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

what im doing wrong?